# "Scollable content size ambiguity" despite hard-coded width and height?

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints, interface-builder

Yes, it's yet another question about this annoying error. I've looked at various other solutions, and so far they haven't worked on what appears to be a simple case. I have a UIScrollView with one subview for content, and then some controls on that subview.

I've hard-coded the height and width of that content subview, but IB is still complaining that they're ambiguous. Any ideas? Thanks!

[image]

UPDATE: If I remember correctly, my next step was to delete the scrollContent's width constraint. IB then offered to add constraints to solve the problem, with the following changes. It has offered a variety of different "solutions" depending on the prevailing constraints, but this is the only one that didn't hard-code the bottom of the scrollview to that of its content (with a numeric offset); such a constraint would, presumably, defeat auto-layout of the scrollview itself for different screen heights.

[image: Before and after IB's solution]

Answer (score 0):

You need to constrain all four edges of the scroll view to its children to fully determine its content area. You have only constrained one of the scroll view's edges to a child: its top edge.

So, get rid of the “scrollContent.centerX = centerX” constraint, keep the “scrollContent.top = top” constraint, and add three new constraints:

- scrollContent.leading = (Scroll View.)leading
- scrollContent.trailing = (Scroll View.)trailing
- scrollContent.bottom = (Scroll View.)bottom

Comment: Thanks, but why would I constrain the scroll view to its child? It needs to occupy a predefined portion of the screen, and act as a viewport to the child material. The scroll view's position on the screen must be defined by constraints to its parent or siblings, must it not? When I do as you suggest, IB complains that the scroll view itself lacks constraints for X position or width, and Y pos or height. This is wrong: I have its width and height equal to the safe area, its top set to safe-area top, and centerX = safe-area's centerX.

Comment: You need constraints from the scroll view to other views outside of the scroll view, in order to define the scroll view's frame in the larger context. You need constraints from the scroll view to its descendants to define the scroll view's content area. Check out [Apple's Technical Note TN2154: UIScrollView And Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2154/_index.html).